# Data inserted in ORACLE TEMPORARY TABLE (from a different session) can be accessed from a scheduler job?

Tags: temp-tables

I have a program to insert current user information into a temporary table (visible only to that user's session / transaction). And I have an oracle scheduler job which sends a mail to admin with the user's information. It seems the user information is not correct (gives wrong values).
 1. Can anyone tell me whether the temp table data be accessed from scheduler?
 2. If so, which session's data it will take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is we can't.
Since TEMPORARY table's data is private ([Reference](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables#creation)).